# Parallelize Convert Sorted Array to Binary Search Tree Function

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, parallel-processing, binary-search-tree

I am trying to parallelize my Convert Sorted Array to BST program in Java. Because my function runs in Divide and Conquer manner, I believe it is parallelizable, but have been stuck with the implementation. It will be very helpful if you guys can tell me how to apply **threads** in here.

Thanks in advance!

```
// Definition for a binary tree node.
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
}

public class Solution {
    public TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] nums) {
        if (nums == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return sortedArrayToBST(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
    }

    private TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] nums, int start, int end) {
        if (start > end) {
            return null;
        }

        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(nums[mid]);
        node.left = sortedArrayToBST(nums, start, mid - 1);
        node.right = sortedArrayToBST(nums, mid + 1, end);

        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: One option is to use a [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).

Comment: @Andreas Cool! Looks like Divide and Conquer is a perfect use case for ForkJoinPool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andreas suggested in the comments ,you could use forkjoinpool to parallelize the binary tree creation

```
 class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
}

class Task extends RecursiveTask<TreeNode>
{
    int[] nums;
    int start,end;
    public Task(int[] nums,int start,int end)
    {
        this.nums =nums;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    protected TreeNode compute()
    {
        if(start>end)
        {
            return null;
        }
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(nums[mid]);
        Task leftSubTask = new Task(nums,start,mid-1);
        Task rightSubTask = new Task(nums,mid+1,end);
        leftSubTask.fork();
        rightSubTask.fork();
        node.left = leftSubTask.join();
        node.right = rightSubTask.join();
        return node;

    }
}
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        int nums[] = {1,5,7,8,9};
        Task task = new Task(nums,0,nums.length-1);
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
        TreeNode root = forkJoinPool.invoke(task);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) API, and found this example would work perfectly with ForkJoinPool. One thing I'm wondering is that if we have to include `Threshold` to define the point where we stop dividing further tasks? Because some tutorials mention that creating subtasks is so expensive?

Comment: Yes creating subtasks is expensive because of overhead. If the depth of the tree is small ,it is better to create it in non parallel recursive approach. In this case ,you could define threshold based on number of nodes in the current iteration(for n nodes the depth is log(n) ).If you want exact point ,then you have to find out using experiments.